# Sending mail with login different from email

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have a problem with this email method:

```
public static void send( final String username, final String password, String recipientEmail, String ccEmail, String title, String message,
                         String from, String host, String port )
    throws AddressException, MessagingException
{
    try
    {
        Session session;

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty( "mail.smtps.host", host );
        props.setProperty( "mail.smtp.port", port );
        props.setProperty( "mail.mime.charset", "utf8" );

        session = Session.getInstance( props, null );
        // session.setDebug( true );

        String uFrom = from;

        // setting encoding properly
        /*
         * try { uFrom = new String( from.getBytes( "UTF-8" ), "ISO-8859-1" ); } catch (
         * UnsupportedEncodingException e ) { // logi ! }
         */

        // -- Create a new message --
        final MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage( session );

        // -- Set the FROM and TO fields --
        msg.setFrom( new InternetAddress( username ) );
        msg.setRecipients( Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse( recipientEmail, false ) );

        if ( ccEmail.length() > 0 )
        {
            msg.setRecipients( Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse( ccEmail, false ) );
        }

        InternetAddress adress = new InternetAddress( username, uFrom );
        adress.setAddress( username + "@naszedziecko.com.pl" );
        adress.setPersonal( uFrom, "ISO-8859-2" );

        msg.setSubject( title, "utf-8" );
        msg.setFrom( adress );
        msg.setText( message, "utf-8" );
        msg.setSentDate( new Date() );

        SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport( "smtps" );

        t.connect( host, username, password );
        t.sendMessage( msg, msg.getAllRecipients() );
        t.close();
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is that my client is using mail where the login is *e.g.* 'superinfo' and the real mail is 'info@domain.com'.

When system is using this mail to send a message I get:

> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 553 5.3.0 <superinfo@domain.com>... No such user

Comment: Check [JavaMail API – Sending email via Gmail SMTP example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/), specifically the `Session session` variable initialization

Comment: you use "mail.smtps.host" which is wrong. please use it correctly "mail.smtp.host"

Comment: why you r using msg.setFrom()  method two times.